# Retrieve robot name

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to retrieve robot name from the urdf in c++?
Or any other way to get it?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272187/retrieve-robot-name/) by [muttidrhummer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32095/muttidrhummer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2017-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andymcevoy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1860/andymcevoy/) on 2017-10-05**:
any reason you need the name? There's got to be an easier way, but you could read the robot description from the parameter server then parse the xml string. If you know you're going to need the name why not load the name into the parameter server in your launch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @muttidrhummer!

I have created a [video](https://youtu.be/V7OMyxxhbVM) that answer exactly this question.

Summarizing, this can be accomplished  by loading a URDF file, parsing it and calling the [getName()](https://github.com/ros/urdfdom_headers/blob/master/urdf_model/include/urdf_model/model.h#L73) method of the C++ Urdf model.

To see how to load and parse a URDF file, you can follow the [Parse a urdf file](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file) tutorial.

After you create your `parser.cpp`, before the `return 0;` you should add

`ROS_INFO("The robot name is: %s", model.getName().c_str());`

to print the name of the robot on the URDF file,  as we can see on the code below:

```
#include <urdf/model.h>
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_parser");
  if (argc != 2){
    ROS_ERROR("Need a urdf file as argument");
    return -1;
  }
  std::string urdf_file = argv[1];

  urdf::Model model;
  if (!model.initFile(urdf_file)){
    ROS_ERROR("Failed to parse urdf file");
    return -1;
  }
  ROS_INFO("Successfully parsed urdf file");
  ROS_INFO("The robot name is: %s", model.getName().c_str());
  return 0;
}
```

After compile the code and generate the executable called `parser` following the [Parse a urdf file](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file) tutorial, you can call it with the path of the URDF file as argument.

Something like:
`rosrun your_package_name parser /path/to/your/file.urdf`

If you still have any doubt, just check the [video](https://youtu.be/V7OMyxxhbVM).

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [muttidrhummer](https://answers.ros.org/users/32095/muttidrhummer/) on 2017-10-18**:
Thanks, works like a charm.

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-18**:
Perfect

You're Welcome.